# Modifying the appearance of appendix titles

Tags: packages, koma-script, appendices

I want to modify the appearance of appendix titles. For that I use the package appendix with the following options:

```
\documentclass[
numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    automark,                               %% Kapitelangaben in Kopfzeile automatisch erstellen
    plainheadsepline,                       %% Linie
    plainfootsepline                        %% Linie
]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                 %% Deutsches Sprachpaket
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 %% Eingabezeichensatz UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    %% Kodierung für Umlaute
\usepackage[
titletoc,
toc, 
page,
title, 
header
]
{appendix}              

\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small}            %% Kopfzeile klein
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}                          %% Kopf-Linie
\setfootsepline{0.4pt}                          %% Fuß-Linie

\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ofoot[]{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter{chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Main}
    ...
\chapter{Practical implementation}
    ...
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

But unfortunately the options title and header seems not to work. It should look like this:

[image]

What could be the reason?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you make your example more minimal and hence the problem more obvious?

Comment: You are loading packages twice, that makes a document hard to maintain. Please have a look at [Minimale Vorlage vs. maximale Probleme](http://www.komascript.de/node/1691) as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B That was a copy and paste error while generating the minimal example

Comment: Your edit did not clearify the question ;-)

Comment: Add `\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}` after `\appendix`.

Comment: Ohhhh, so simple :/ And is there a solution to get the prefix and the chapter name on one line?

Comment: There might be, i don't know. Be aware that you are inconsistent with your main stuff if there is no `chapterprefix`. But i guess you want to redefine `\thechapter`

Comment: Next problem is that when I insert a list of contents, the prefix still is not visible there.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Answering the 'main' question here, perhaps?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, not really. Maybe esdd wants to answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}` after starting the appendix.

[image: mraeAppendix]

```
\documentclass[
ngerman,
numbers=noenddot,
headsepline,
footsepline 
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    automark,       
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mwepage}

\usepackage[
titletoc,
toc, 
page,
title, 
header
]{appendix}


\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
    \KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\chapter{Wombat}
\chapter{Capybara}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```